# Insert data into range of rows in PgAdmin + PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, pgadmin-4

Just created a table with 1000 rows. When I trying to add 1000 rows of data into specific column, PgAdmin just create another 1000 rows in same column and in total I have 2000 rows.
Used command: insert into Table_Name (column_name) values ('1956-08-07');

Want to add 1000 rows of data in a range of rows of any column.
How to add data started (as example) from row 1 of column_name and end with row 1000?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use update statement instead of insert.
Should look like this:

```
update Table_Name set column_name = '1956-08-07'
```

This will update the value of column_name for each row.

Comment: Thank you, but when I added 1000 rows (like below), system just update all 1000 rows in specific column with only last value. Mean all updated rows have same date, it just multiplied instead to add different value in each row. Any idea how to avoid that?
Sample entries:
UPDATE people SET dateofbirth = '1958-09-13'; @Jakub

Comment: Result by link:  https://imgur.com/a9VmBwW
@Jakub